# Ignore scanner input if timer is running, else run timer for x number of seconds (x = scanner input)

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am trying to use a scanner object to continually pass Long values to a timer. If the timer is *not* in use, the timer object should run for the number of seconds specified by the Long value, then print "Timer is complete". If it *is* already in use, the program should print "Timer already in use", and **ignore** the Long value. Once the timer completes the previous job, it should accept the next Long value from the scanner and begin a countdown of the specified number of seconds again. At the moment I have the code below, which just queues the jobs sequentially and waits until the timer is free before running the next one, rather than ignoring intermediary requests when the timer is busy. I have added the task.isAlive() check to help me understand what's going on, any help would be really appreciated.

Current output for scanner values 3,10,1,3:

```
Thread-0 is not alive.
3
Timer is done!
Thread-1 is not alive.
10
Timer is done!
Thread-2 is not alive.
1
Timer is done!
Thread-3 is not alive.
3
Timer is done!
```

Desired output for scanner values 3,10,1,3 (would involve removing the additional print statements currently in use for debugging)

```
Timer is complete // for 3
Timer already in use // for 1
Timer already in use // for 3
Timer is complete // for 10
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Timer extends TimerTask implements Runnable {

    Long sleepTime;

    Timer(Long inputTime) {
        sleepTime = inputTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try { 
            System.out.println(sleepTime);
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000);
            System.out.println("Timer is complete");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(sleepTime);
            System.out.println("Timer already in use");
        }
    }
}


public class TimerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            Long inpt = in.nextLong();
            Runnable t = new Timer(inpt);
            Thread task = new Thread(t);
            if (task.isAlive()) {
                System.out.format("Timer already in use");
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s is not alive.%n", task.getName());
                task.start();
            try {
                task.join();
              }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("Timer already in use");
              }
            }

   }
        in.close();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new `Thread` object in each iteration and check if `isAlive` on that newly created object. It will never be true as you check it before starting it.

You need to store the object between iteration. Then if the previous `Thread` is either null or not working, you create a new one in place of the previous one. The code could look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Thread task = null;
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        Long inpt = in.nextLong();
        Runnable t = new Timer(inpt);
        if (task != null && task.isAlive()) {
            System.out.format("Timer already in use");
        } else {
            task = new Thread(t);
            System.out.format("%s is not alive.%n", task.getName());
            task.start();
        }
    }
    in.close();
}
```